# Trouble finding what ports are in use Windows 10 / Docker

Tags: windows-10, docker, wsl2

I'm using Laravel sail (i.e. docker). After doing a `sail up -d` I get the following:

```
Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:5173 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5173: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
```

Where 5173 is a port used by Vite. From there I run the following to attempt to find the culprit:

```
Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 5173).OwningProcess
```

Which returns the following:

```
Get-NetTCPConnection: No MSFT_NetTCPConnection objects found with property 'LocalPort' equal to '5173'.  Verify the value of the property and retry.
Get-Process: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Id' because it is null.
```

(I have also tried running the command as administrator and also tried running the Linux equivalent (`lsof -i tcp:5173`) in WSL both of which also yielded nothing)

What could possibly cause the port not to be available if it doesn't show up in that PowerShell command?

Comment: Do you have Vite installed? Have you tried changing the port to Laravel?

Comment: Try Nirsoft's CuurPorts to list all ports and their usage: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html